# How do I restrict cd arguments to directories in bash?

Tags: linux, bash, cd, archlinux

Currently, when I cd re[tab][tab], bash gives me options including files and directories. Since cd only allows directories as arguments, giving me non-directory options doesn't seem to offer any advantages. How can I modify it to only give directories as options? I'm using archlinux.

```
$ cd re
redrover.sh  research/
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bash already hase some pretty nice completion, but you can get this (and much more) if you install the advanced auto-completion:

```
pacman -S bash-completion
```

Comment: This essentially adds the bash_completion script into the correct directory. It does a lot more than what I asked to do, but I guess I'll slowly figure them out. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this post: http://embraceubuntu.com/2006/01/28/turn-on-bash-smart-completion/

Comment: After looking into this, it seems that this only works if you have an existing /etc/bash_completion script. Arch checks for this script in /usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion, and it's non-existent. After checking the bash_completion file on a nearby ubuntu computer, it seems the command "complete -d pushd" is used for this purpose, but editing this into my bash_completion script didn't yield results. I'll keep trying.